# Load content on anchor link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have content that is hidden by default. On button click, I want the selected one to show its content. I.e if find more is clicked on the second `div`, show the content for that div.

**Approach so far:**

```js
function showClass(a) {
  var e = [];
  var e = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
  for (elem of e) {
    if (!elem) return true;

    if (elem.style.display == "none") {
      elem.style.display = "block"
    } else {
      elem.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
    <li>list 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>list 7</li>
    <li>list 8</li>
    <li>list 9</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<a onclick="showClass('list');" class="loadMoreBtn">Find out more</a>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: your html is invalid - you cannot have a p as a child of ul, you declare `e` twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You should use [`document.getElementsByClassName(a);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (note the `document`)
2. To iterate through a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (returned by `getElementsByClassName`) you should use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or a regular [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) loop. [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/for...in) is not a recommended way to iterate a collection as it is made to iterate over properties in an object. Thus, the `for..in` loop can give unexpected properties of the HTMLCollection such as its `length` when using it to iterate (when instead all you're after is the node)

```js
function showClass(a) {
  // var e = []; <-- no need for this \/ redeclared below
  var e = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
  for (elem of e) {
    if (!elem) return true;

    if (elem.style.display == "none") {
      elem.style.display = "block"
    } else {
      elem.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <p>sample text</p>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
    <li>list 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <p>sample text</p>
    <li>list 7</li>
    <li>list 8</li>
    <li>list 9</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<a onclick="showClass('list');" class="loadMoreBtn">Find out more</a>
```

To have separate buttons for each item/div you can give each item an id, and then toggle the id by passing it through as an argument:

```js
function showClass(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  var visible = getComputedStyle(elem).display == "block";
  if (!visible) {
    elem.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="list" id="list-one">
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list" id="list-two">
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
    <li>list 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list" id="list-three">
    <li>list 7</li>
    <li>list 8</li>
    <li>list 9</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<a onclick="showClass('list-one');" class="loadMoreBtn">Find out more - Item 1</a>
<br />
<a onclick="showClass('list-two');" class="loadMoreBtn">Find out more - Item 2</a>
<br />
<a onclick="showClass('list-three');" class="loadMoreBtn">Find out more - Item 3</a>
```

Comment: Ah, progress! However, is it possible to only get one `list` item to load? So if I have three `item` divs, and each one has a ``loadMoreBtn`, onclick of that `loadMoreBtn`, I only want that div's content to show? I've slightly edited my markup too, which is reflected in the quesiton

Comment: @Freddy yes there is a way to do that, you can see the code in the collapsed code snippet in my answer

Comment: @Freddy no worries ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged the question with jQuery and you're including it, you should really use it for this since it's very simple, concise and readable code...

```js
function toggleClass(className) {
    $("." + className).toggle();
}
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <p>sample text</p>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
    <li>list 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <p>sample text</p>
    <li>list 7</li>
    <li>list 8</li>
    <li>list 9</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<a onclick="toggleClass('list');" class="loadMoreBtn">Find out more</a>
```

As you can see, jQuery has a `toggle()` method that toggles visibility, and jQuery methods work on arrays of elements by default, so you don't need a loop and you don't need to check the current visible state of anything.

You could also go a bit further and assign the event handler in Javascript, rather than inline in the anchor element, like this...

```
$(".loadMoreBtn").on("click", function() {
    $(".list").toggle();
});
```

Keeping your Javascript out of HTML is encouraged, as it means you don't have to hunt different files to find it, which is great for both you and anyone else that ever has to look at your code.

Answer (score -1):

Please have look at below code i have madden few changes in your code

```
function showClass(a) {
  var e = [];
  var e = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
  console.log(e);
  for (i=0;i<=e.length;i++) {
    if (!e[i]) return true;
    e[i].classList.add("displayblock");
  }
  return true;
}
function removeClass(a) {
  var e = [];
  var e = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
  console.log(e);
  for (i=0;i<= e.length;i++) {
    if (!e[i]) return true;
    e[i].classList.remove("displayblock");
  }
  return true;
}
```

Styles

```
.list {
  display: none;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.displayblock{
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <ul class="list">
      <p>sample text</p>
      <li>list 1</li>
      <li>list 2</li>
      <li>list 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>list 4</li>
      <li>list 5</li>
      <li>list 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <ul class="list">
      <p>sample text</p>
      <li>list 7</li>
      <li>list 8</li>
      <li>list 9</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <a onclick="showClass('list');">Find out more</a>
  <a onclick="removeClass('list');">Hide more</a>
```

Share your improve reference

Answer (score -2):

Read the error messsage,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsByClassName is not defined

The actual method you are looking for is window.document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: No need to add `window.document`, just `document` will work as well and looks a bit neater in my opinion.

Comment: You didn't write "document", the "window" was for good measures